# Least upper bound of character of representation of compact Lie group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, compactness, characters

I’m asked to show given a complex representation $V$ of a compact matrix Lie group $G$, the character of $V$ has the least upper bound dim$(V)$. It’s not clear to me what knowledge of character should I use to cut in to solve this question. I’m appreciate if you can give a slight hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG $\rho(g)$ is unitary (from the averaging trick), in which case $\rho(g)$ is diagonalizable. What can we say about its eigenvalues, and what do they have to do with its trace?

Comment: I should embed the unitary trick into my head...